# Актуальность .html и .php в конце адресов

Tags: seo, .htaccess

Я заметил на многих сайтах в конце адресов имеется расширение '.html' или же '.php'. Это не могут быть отдельные файлы, так как движку сайта пришлось бы генерировать страницы при любом обновлении информации (это я так, на всякий случай уточнил). Ссылка выглядит примерно таким образом:

```
http://www.site.my/Articles/Read/7/Tile_Entity.html
```

И вот мне стало интересно, насколько необходимо оставлять в самом конце такое расширение? Влияет ли это как-то на СЕО или еще что-либо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раньше на это обращали внимание поисковики, но сейчас это уже не актуально. Можете взглянуть на адреса того же хэшкода, у него нет в конце ни .html, ни .php

Comment: Это само собой. Просто даже на новых сайтах такую фичу видел. 
Вот и заинтересовала меня эта штука.

Comment: @oliverfoxi вероятно, сеошники на этих проектах все еще думают, что это на что то влияет. Либо же просто им нравятся такие урлы

Comment: @Demyan112rv, спасибо за ответ. Сам я в этой области недавно, поэтому знаю не очень много.

Comment: Думаю, что расширение html в самом конце удобно тем, что если пользователь сохранит страницу, то она получит нормальное имя и потом будет открываться. В противном случае нужно либо надеяться, что браузер сам пофиксит, либо, что пользователь переименует.

Удобство для пользователя - это лучше, чем видимось ненужной страницы в поиске.